# remove() Handling of STL Multi-Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-leaks, stl

We have created three STL and STL-inherited data types for use in a clustering algorithm:

```
typedef std::vector<double>Point;   // A list of parameters (a single observation)

struct Cluster : std::list<Point> {   // A list of Points
   // Additional member variables
   Point centroid;
   bool centroid_valid;
   bool sort_valid;
   // Cluster functions omitted
};

struct Universe : std::list<Cluster> {   // A list of Clusters
   // No member variables
   // Universe functions omitted
};
```

This is an attempt to fully utilize the STL so nothing is `new`'d into existence. The concern is having to do with the nature of subordinated STL functionality, specifically:

If we were to `remove()` a `Cluster` element from a `Universe` list, would the STL handle not only the deletion (and memory management) of all `Point`s in the `Cluster` to be removed, but also the deletion-handling of all member variables?

Note: all member functions are relatively simple, with no static operations.

Comment: Yes. But it's a bad idea to inherit standard containers. A universe *has* a number of clusters, but that's not everything it *is*.

Comment: These type of standard containers aren't really intended to be inherited.

Comment: Here's another reason not to inherit: Let's say in the future you need to change the storage of a Cluster to be, say, an Eigen matrix, so that operations can be batched up and optimized over the entire matrix.  You don't want your interface to be forced into the STL interface, but instead by appropriate to your datatype: `Cluster::AddPoint()` for example.

Comment: I see - so, the point of the inheritance was to leverage the STLs' mutability, specifically with deletion and iteration. Is the general recommendation to formulate structs with the STL as a member, instead of inherit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If we were to remove() a Cluster element from a Universe list, would
>   the STL handle not only the deletion (and memory management) of all
>   Points in the Cluster to be removed, but also the deletion-handling of
>   all member variables?

Yes it will because it operates on Cluster objects and removing it will remove all its fields. But inheritance from standard containers is considered to be a bad practice because they do not have a virtual destructor. It is better to store list of Points in a Cluster as a property.

Comment: Thank you - can you expand on what you mean by, "It is better to store list of Points in a Cluster as a property?"

Comment: @Miller it means it's better to aggregate rather than inherit from.

Answer (score 1):

wrong:

```
typedef std::vector<double>Point;   // A list of parameters (a single observation)

struct Cluster : std::list<Point> {   // A list of Points
   // Additional member variables
   Point centroid;
   bool centroid_valid;
   bool sort_valid;
   // Cluster functions omitted
};
```

right:

```
typedef std::vector<double>Point;   // A list of parameters (a single observation)

struct Cluster {   // A list of Points

   std::list<Point> points;

   // Additional member variables
   Point centroid;
   bool centroid_valid;
   bool sort_valid;
   // Cluster functions omitted
};
```

When you inherit from a class, you are inherently guaranteeing that all of its member functions will behave sanely when called against your class.

The problem for you is that the 'additional member variables' are cached observations of the points. If you `erase` or `insert` a point, these cached observations will be out of sync, and therefore *wrong*.

If you want Cluster to have the same interface as std::list, then you must implement that interface, call into the member `points` and update (or mark as invalid) the cached observations.